# Which one is the correct sentence? "Forever shall I remain indebted" or "I shall forever remain indebted"

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

I came across an acknowledgement in one of the theses which came for correction to me. The opening sentence says: "Forever shall I remain indebted to....". Is it the correct way of writing? In my opinion it should be: "Forever I shall remain indebted to...". Please correct me.

Comment: You may want to go though this long/rich [AUE thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/alt.usage.english/%22I$20shall$20remain%22/alt.usage.english/WKFFJkXLids/cUZSaV1rQVQJ). Watch esp for Professor Lawler's commentary.

Comment: Either is correct, though the both are a bit archaic.  "Normal" modern, non-poetic usage would be "I shall(or will) remain indebted forever."

Answer (score 5):

When the usual subject-verb order is inverted, it is called [inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(linguistics)#Inversion_in_English). It occurs naturally in interrogative sentences, e.g. *"Were you here yersterday?"*; in stories with direct speech, e.g. *"Hi", said the rabbit.*. In your particular example, the inversion is used for emphasis, putting it on the word *forever*, which is brought to the beginning of the sentence - an unusual position for it. It should be noted that this construct is rather literary. Other examples include:

> Up went the balloon!
>
> Into the dungeon came three masked men.
>
> Not until hours later did I find him.

Answer (score 1):

Both the sentences are equally correct. The former is used more in dialogues or poetry, the latter is a statement. The writer may write - "Forever shall I remain indebted to....". The use also is grammatically correct. Here of the sentence has a tinge of declaration. So we may consider it correct.

The normal order of the sentence would have been "Forever I shall remain indebted to..." or "I shall remain indebted to...(sb/sth)...forever". But they are plain statements.

So if the writer wishes to be poetic or have some force in his tone he should use - "Forever shall I remain indebted to....".

Comment: The ***normal*** order is *"I shall forever remain indebted ..."*, or *"I shall remain indebted ... forever."*. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Forever+I+shall%2CForever+shall+I%2C+I+shall+forever&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CForever%20I%20shall%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CForever%20shall%20I%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20shall%20forever%3B%2Cc0). Neither of the OP's choices is normal, and *"Forever shall I ..."* is more literary and poetic.